# Generating plain text from a Wikipedia database dump

Tags: python, xml, database, shell, wikipedia

I found a Python script ([here: Wikipedia Extractor](http://medialab.di.unipi.it/wiki/Wikipedia_Extractor)) that can generate plain text from [(English) Wikipedia database dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20140304/).
When I use this command (as it's stated on the script's page):

```
$ python enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml WikiExtractor.py -b 500K -o extracted
```

I get this error:

> File "enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml", line 1
>   < mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.8/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.8/http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.8.xsd" version="0.8" xml:lang="en">

```
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm executing the script using Python 2.7.6 & Cygwin on Windows 7.

I hope If anyone has already used this script or experience with Python can help me to solve this error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17):

The first argument to `python` should be the script name.

You probably need to swap `xml` and `py` file names:

```
$ python WikiExtractor.py enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml -b 500K -o extracted
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although the right order is what I've used as it's stated in the script's page, I tried with what you've suggested and got this: "Usage: WikiExtractor.py [options]", which means the file name should come first.

Comment: @Asim I think you are almost right - in terms of the contents of the file should be piped to the wiki extractor, like `cat enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml | python WikiExtractor.py -b 500K -o extracted`. Give it a try.

Comment: Wow, finally it works! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.