# Wikipedia Extractor produces empty file

Tags: wikipedia

I just want to follow up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772952/generating-plain-text-from-a-wikipedia-database-dump).

So, I downloaded the Wikipedia dump of February 2014 and run the command with `WikiExtractor.py` as suggested:

```
cat mywiki-pages-articles.xml | python WikiExtractor.py -b 500K -o extracted
```

However, after more than one running hour, I got nothing but an empty file named wiki_00.

Do you have any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: I think you need to do some debugging on your own first, it's hard to guess what's going without a single error message. Try adding print statments in `WikiExtractor.py` to follow step by step what's going on. Does it read content the article from the xml? If so, does the parsing return any content? Etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, So I found the solution for this problem.

Last time when I run the command above I added the "screen" instruction before it. In this case, screen will just cat the xml file without tuning it to the WikiExtractor.py. The result is therefore an empty file.

I fixed this by putting the above command in a file, making the file runnable and run the screen command on it.